# Copy Excel Range (Formatting and Values) and paste into the body of new outlook message

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, formatting

So I am trying to get this to copy a range from another section listed as a variable 'Temp' so how do I get VBA to copy the range Temp in excel and paste the formatting and values into outlook body?

```
Sub OutlookMessage()
Dim OutApp
Dim objOutlookMsg
Dim objOutlookRecip
Dim Recipients
Dim SubjLine As String
Dim MonSubjLine As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sndRange As Range
Dim Sunday
Dim Monday
Dim Today As Integer
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Recipients = objOutlookMsg.Recipients
Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("Recipient")
objOutlookRecip.Type = 1
    objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Sender"
                Today = Weekday(Date, vbMonday)
                    If Today = 1 Then
                        Sunday = Date - 1
                        Monday = Date - 7
                    End If
        MonSubjLine = "WEEK " & (DatePart("ww", Date, vbMonday) - 1) & " - PHONE REPORT (" & Monday & " Th " & Sunday & ")"
        SubjLine = StrConv(WeekdayName(Weekday(Date - 1, vbMonday), False, vbMonday), vbUpperCase) & " (" & Date - 1 & ") PHONE REPORT"
        Today = Weekday(Date, vbMonday)
            If Today > 1 Then
                objOutlookMsg.Subject = SubjLine
            ElseIf Today = 1 Then
                objOutlookMsg.Subject = MonSubjLine
            End If
    objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = "How to Get My Table In Here?"
For Each objOutlookRecip In objOutlookMsg.Recipients
objOutlookRecip.Resolve
Next
objOutlookMsg.Display
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I ended up just using this to paste it

```
SendKeys "^({v})", True
```

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm has a ton of different examples...

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend [Ron de Bruin's Site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail4.htm) for automating e-mails from Excel to Outlook.  For example:

```
Sub Mail_Range()
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set Source = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Range("A1:K50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Selection of " & wb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "ron@debruin.nl"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three ways for body manipulations.

1. The [Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) property - a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The HTMLBody property - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. The HTMLBody property should be an HTML syntax string. Setting the HTMLBody property will always update the Body property immediately.
3. The Word object model. The [WordEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the body of your email.

All theses ways are described in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in depth. It is up to you which way is to choose.